# How to paginate search result using php pdo?

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

I am creating a pagination for search result all looks fine on first loading page,
but when I click on paginated links then it show me a white page (search page but without entries in).
simply with no results found from my data

This is the site search box in index.php

```
<form action="search/" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="word..." required />
<input type="submit" name="submit_search" class="search-btn" value="" />
</form>
```

> Here is my setup for `htaccess` pagination:

```
RewriteRule ^search/page/(.*)$ search.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

it looks fine on browser.

> Here is my search page codes:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit_search']) && !empty($search)){
    $search = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['search']), ENT_QUOTES);
    $perpage = intval("12");

    $n_stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
    $n_stmt->execute(); 
    $total_posts = $n_stmt->rowCount();

    $total_pages = ceil($total_posts/$perpage);

    $page = !empty($_GET['page']) && intval($_GET['page']) ? (int) intval($_GET['page']) : intval("1");
    if($page < intval("1")) $page = intval("1");
    if($page > $total_pages) $page = $total_pages;
    $limit = ($page - intval("1")) * $perpage;

    $pages_to_show = intval("10");

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE :search OR subject LIKE :search OR descriptions LIKE :search OR keywords LIKE :search ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
    $stmt->bindValue(":search","%".$search."%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(":limit",$limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(":perpage",$perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if($stmt->execute()){
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){?>

    <div class="news_box">
    <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['news_url']);?>/" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['title']);?>">
        <div class="title"><h2><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['title']);?></h2></div>
        <div class="image">
        <img src="images/posts/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['img']);?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['title']);?>"/></div>
        <div class="spot"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['subject']);?></div>
    </a>
    </div>

    <?php 
        }
    }
}
unset($stmt);
?>
```

> Here is my pagination part:

```
<div class="pagination">    
<?php if($page >1){?>
    <a href="search/page/1/">First</a>
    <a href="search/page/<?php echo $page - intval("1");?>">previous</a>                
    <?php } for($i = $page - $pages_to_show; $i < $page + $pages_to_show + 1; $i++){ 
        if($i > 0 and $i <= $total_pages){
            if($i == $page){?>
                <a href="search/page/<?php echo intval($i);?>" class="active"><?php echo intval($i);?></a>
            <?php }else{?>
            <a href="search/page/<?php echo intval($i);?>"><?php echo $i;?></a>
            <?php   
            }
        }
    ?>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php if($page != $total_pages){?>
    <a href="search/page/<?php echo $page + intval("1");?>">Next</a>
    <a href="search/page/<?php echo $total_pages;?>">Last</a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you're emulating prepared statements you can't use the same named parameter multiple times (as you have done with `:search`)

Comment: it works fine in other pages accept in search result @Nick

Comment: No its not a completely white page, its same search page but doesn't have any posts in it, just a white search page,simply with no results found from database, it doesnt display any errors in php `E_ALL` or in `error.log` file, I tried it. I am probably having problem with link parameters, values coming from search box, I added search box code to main question. @David